# Sum function is not working properly

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am using Excel to import Data from one excel workbook to another via Data query.
The problem is:
when I try to use the Sum function, the numbers do not add up and it just shows a 0 even though the numbers are formatted as numbers and not as  text.

Comment: Provide a sample example that makes your problem reproducible

Comment: One trick to try is to multiply each number by one during the process.

Answer (score 0):

If cells **A1** through **A10** appear to have values, but the sum shows ***0***, then the values are probably Text.

Pick another cell and enter the array formula:

```
=SUM(--TRIM(A1:A10))
```

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done correctly, the formula will appear with curly braces around it in the Formula Bar.

[image]

Comment: The justification also differs between text and numbers.

Comment: @Acccumulation  YES! that is a good clue!